# Return String with null value

Tags: java

I have a few constants like below:

```
public String name;
public String surname;
public String age;
public String postcode;
```

And if one of this value `== null` then I must return information about this, I can do this like here:

```
if(name == null && surname == null && age == null && postcode == null) {
      return "You need to provide: name, surname, age and postcode";
} else if(name == null) {
      return "You need to provide name";
} else if(age == null) {
      return "You need to provide age";
} //etc.
```

I do not want to do this like above, is there any better solutions with using e.g. `Optional`?

Comment: Why do you not what to do this like above? Are there any specific reasons?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Those aren't constants but just regular fields. Instead of writing large if statements use the Java Validation API to do validation, combined with Spring you will get automatic validation.

Comment: Make your Strings Optional, or use switch case, if-else construction - why not man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional is an unrelated dimension to this issue.

```
List<String> missing = new ArrayList<String>();
if (name == null) missing.add("name");
if (surname == null) missing.add("surname");
if (age == null) missing.add("age");
if (postcode == null) missing.add("postcode");

if (missing.isEmpty()) return null;
if (missing.size() == 1) return "You need to provide " + missing.get(0));
return "You need to provide: " +
  String.join(", ", missing.subList(0, missing.size() - 1)) +
  " and " +
  missing.get(missing.length() - 1);
```

You've made things quite a bit more complicated by wanting considerably different formatting depending on whether there is 1 or multiple missing fields, and by injecting the 'and' aspect.

NB: Asking for 'name' and 'surname' is a silly thing to do. Well over half the planet's population has a name that does not fit in that mold. Just ask for 'name', one string, that's all you need. Also, 'age' is rather obviously not a String.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `java.util.Objects#requireNonNull(T)`.

Here is it's java doc:

> Checks that the specified object reference is not null. This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors, as demonstrated below:

```java
public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = Objects.requireNonNull(bar);
}
```

If object is `null` then `NullPointerException` will be thrown. And you can handle it as you want. E.g. with one of the messages from the code you provided.

Comment: The user need to return a custom string message specific to each field. `requiresNonNull` would throw an exception and stop the execution